# Ball collides with another. Find velocities

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

A ball moving at a velocity of 5.0 m/s east when it collided with an identical ball at rest. Both balls are the same mass.

The first ball moved at 60 degrees north of east. The second went 30 degrees south.

How would I calculate the velocities of the balls?

Answer (score 1):

This is a question of momentum transfer. You can see [momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum) here on Wikipedia. My guess is you're looking at Newtonian (not relativistic), elastic (not *in*elastic) collisions, but you'll need to check with your teacher or problem description. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision) Wikipedia page has more information on elastic collisions, with information specific to your problem under the [two-dimensional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision#Two-dimensional) section (though understanding the one-dimensional stuff first will help).

Judging from the question, I'm guessing it's a homework problem. You should have an assigned textbook, which should have sections on the above, and they should be written in a more natural order to learn them. Go through each section, read the section, do some problems related to what you just read. Once you get to the section on elastic collisions, you should have all the tools you need to solve the problem, though you may have two sections -- one on one-dimensional collisions, then a later section on multi-dimensional collisions -- in which case you'll want to read through to the second section.

At that point, if you get halfway through the problem and just can't figure out where to go next, come back, edit your question to show what you're attempting and what part you're getting stuck on. If you're having trouble even getting to the appropriate part of the book, you should really have a chat with your teacher, who is in a better position to help you catch up than we are.

Comment: Thanks for sending OP back to the book for some self-instruction. +1

Answer (score 1):

By using conservation of momentum.

Northward component of momentum of first ball has to be equal and opposite of southward component of momentum of second ball.

Eastward components of momentum of both balls have to add up to original momentum of first ball.

Homework type question, so please do the rest yourself.